# Can we add filter to MongoDB nested object struct?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a problem when querying mongoDB with nested objects notation:
**My Struct**

```
profileId:"1"
countries:Array
  0:Object
    countryCode:"999"
    isMain:true
  1:Object
    countryCode: "AZ"
    isMain:false
  2:Object
    countryCode:"KG"
    isMain:false
```

Currently I am using query like in python:

```
p = [c["countryCode"] for c in record["countries"]]
```

What I want is when `isMain` is true I need `countryCode`. Can it be possible to do this in python?

I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am expecting nested object notation to return the same result as the dot notation query. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can add a conndition to the list comprehension `[c["countryCode"] for c in record["countries"] if c["isMain"]]`, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: ... or are you looking for a database query so that only the fields you want are returned?